# How to define function from input string in python at runtime?

Tags: python, c++, function, parsing, runtime

I was trying to solve [UVA 11036](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1977). It requires defining function at runtime.

For Example: I have to take input `(2*x + 7) % N` as a string and define a function at runtime like `func = lambda x : (2*x + 7) % N` to work on it. Please help me to find out how to convert string to function at runtime.

Comment: Please explain how this is related to C++.

Comment: Use `exec()` to execute a statement in a string.

Comment: That problem doesn't require defining a function from a string. You should parse the RPN and generate a function dynamically using functional composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use exec to define a function from a string. However that allows to inject any code into your program. But as it's only for solving that challenge, it might be fine.

```py
exec 'func = lambda x : '+input
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems captivating riddle, so if you want to solve it in C++ have two way. The hard way is implementing a small math parser using some algorithms like [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Or instead of, if you are familiar with  library linking in C++, it is better to use a mathematical expression parser libraries. There are many libraries on Internet. Here, I suggest one of them as below.

[mathematical expression library](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/) I personalty have tested it and obviously is fast. you can clone  [source code](https://github.com/ArashPartow/exprtk) in GitHub

Anyway, you can not solve this case with **lambda functions**  because, the input is a mathematical expression you should parse and calculate it runtime.

if you use python see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string).

Comment: did you mean http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/index.html

Comment: @rioV8 Yes it is that.